# I've defined a bundle Controller and Routing, but I get "Error: the controller does neither exist as service nor as class"

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have created a controller class under a module directory in Symfony 4. My bundle's routing file references it. My root's routing file includes the bundle's routing file.

However I get an error 500, "Error: the controller does neither exist as service nor as class".

Why?

**root/src/MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.YML**

```
route_name:
  path: /test3
  controller: MyBundle\Controller\ExportCsvController::exportProductInCsv
  options:
    expose: true
```

**root/config/routes/my_custom_routes.YML**

```
route_name:
      resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
      prefix:   /
```

**root/src/MyBundle/Controller/ExportCsvController.PHP**

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ExportCsvController extends Controller
{
    public function exportProductInCsv(): Response
    {
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>test</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Bundles are not usually autowired.  Typically you would have a bundle extension which in turn loads the bundles services.yaml file which in turn would define your controller service.  You can use "bin/console debug:container MyBundle to verify that this is the issue.

Comment: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` <--- It was a cache problem^^ About your comment: I don't know what you mean by "autowired"? I don't know what is a "bundle extension"? I don't know what is the file `services.yaml` that belong to bundles? What is a "controller service"? I don't know the effect of this command. ^^ But I solved my problem by emptying the Symfony cache :) ! I will read the docs to learn about your all of these concepts.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Clearing the cache is also my go to magic solution that works a surprising number of time.  Be aware that you don't usually make bundles anymore in Symfony unless the intent is to share the bundle with multiple application.  The docs talk about creating bundles and all the service stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a problem of cache (Symfony cache). Solved with this command: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`. Now the content of the file `root/src/MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.YML` is correctly taken into account :).